# When connected via ssh, can I run a command on the remote (code .) then translate it to a command on the client (code --remote ssh@/path/to/dir)?

Tags: ssh

I would like to be able to run `code .` when connected to my remote server via ssh and have that translate to `code --remote ssh-remote+client-name /path/to/directory` on the client.

This would essentially just need to provide the information to the server indicating the path to the directory that needs to be "remoted into".

Does SSH allow for such back chatter?

I can see that I have access the the `$SSH_CLIENT` variable. I could possibly run an ssh command back at the client but then I would need to have an exposed ssh server running on the client with the correct forwarded ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you clearly understand that your `code` command will have to be an alias or function or some script.

That said, you should be able to use reverse port forwarding to allow the `remote` to `ssh` into your client **without** opening your client to the "internet", or having any ports forwarded through your firewall/router/whatever.  Something like this:

```
user@client $ ssh -R 22122:localhost:22 user2@remote
user2@remote $ ssh user@localhost:22122 'whoami;hostname'
  user
  client
```

Passwords or ssh-key access from `remote` to `client`, and the rest of your `code` script, is left for you, but if you are using keys and an `ssh-agent`, you should be able to also forward agent access from client to remote using the `-A` option.

Caveat Usor: since you are effectively allowing someone to connect to your client from the remote, which if it's a shared remote, may be problematic.